# What cache invalidation algorithms are used in actual CPU caches?

Tags: algorithm, caching, cpu-cache

I came to the topic caching and mapping and cache misses and how the cache blocks get replaced in what order when all blocks are already full.

There is the least recently used algorithm or the fifo algorithm or the least frequently algorithm and random replacement, ...

But what algorithms are used on actual cpu caches? Or can you use all and the... operating system decides what the best algorithm is?

---

Edit: Even when i chose an answer, any further information is welcome ;)

Comment: I guess that lots of those are trade secrets... So I'm not sure you'll get a very accurate answer here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As hivert said - it's hard to get a clear picture on the specific algorithm, but one can deduce some of the information according to hints or clever reverse engineering.

You didn't specify which CPU you mean, each one can have a different policy (actually even within the same CPU different cache levels may have different policies, not to mention TLBs and other associative arrays which also may have such policies). I did find a few hints about Intel (specifically Ivy bridge), so we'll use this as a benchmark for industry level "standards" (which may or may not apply elsewhere).

First, Intel presented some LRU related features here -
http://www.hotchips.org/wp-content/uploads/hc_archives/hc24/HC24-1-Microprocessor/HC24.28.117-HotChips_IvyBridge_Power_04.pdf

Slide 46 mentioned "Quad-Age LRU" - this is apparently an age based LRU that assigned some "age" to each line according to its predicted importance. They mention that prefetches get middle age, so demands are probably allocated at a higher age (or lower, whatever survives longest), and all lines likely age gradually, so the oldest gets replaced first. Not as good as perfect "fifo-like" LRU, but keep in mind that most caches don't implement that, but rather a complicated [pseudo-LRU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-LRU) solution, so this might be an improvement.

Another interesting mechanism mentioned there, which goes the extra mile beyond classic LRU, is adaptive fill policy. There's a pretty good analysis here - http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/ , but in a nutshell (if the blog is correct, and he does seem to make a good match with his results), the cache dynamically chooses between two LRU policies, trying to decide whether the lines are going to be reused or not (and should be kept or not).

I guess this could answer to some extent your question on multiple LRU schemes. Implementing several schemes is probably hard and expensive in terms of HW, but when you have some policy that's complicated enough to have parameters, it's possible to use tricks like dynamic selection, set dueling , etc..

Answer (score 11):

The following are some examples of replacement policies used in actual processors.

The PowerPC 7450's 8-way L1 cache used binary tree pLRU. Binary tree pLRU uses one bit per pair of ways to set an LRU for that pair, then an LRU bit for each pair of *pairs of ways*, etc. The 8-way L2 used pseudo-random replacement settable by privileged software (the OS) as using either a 3-bit counter incremented every clock cycle or a shift-register-based pseudo-random number generator.

The StrongARM SA-1110 32-way L1 data cache used FIFO. It also had a 2-way minicache for transient data, which also seems to have used FIFO. (*Intel StrongARM SA-1110 Microprocessor Developer’s Manual* states "Replacements in the minicache use the same round-robin pointer mechanism as in the main data cache. However, since this cache is only two-way set-associative, the replacement algorithm reduces to a simple least-recently-used (LRU) mechanism."; but 2-way FIFO is *not* the same as LRU even with only two ways, though for streaming data it works out the same.])

The HP PA 7200 had a 64-block fully associative "assist cache" that was accessed in parallel with an off-chip direct-mapped data cache. The assist cache used FIFO replacement with the option of evicting to the off-chip L1 cache. Load and store instructions had a "locality only" hint; if an assist cache entry was loaded by such a memory access, it would be evicted to memory bypassing the off-chip L1.

For 2-way associativity, true LRU might be the most common choice since it has good behavior (and, incidentally, is the same as binary tree pLRU when there are only two ways). E.g., the Fairchild Clipper Cache And Memory Management Unit used LRU for its 2-way cache. FIFO is slightly cheaper than LRU since the replacement information is only updated when the tags are written anyway, i.e., when inserting a new cache block, but has better behavior than counter-based pseudo-random replacement (which has even lower overhead). The HP PA 7300LC used FIFO for its 2-way L1 caches.

The Itanium 9500 series (Poulson) uses NRU for L1 and L2 data caches, L2 instruction cache, and the L3 cache (L1 instruction cache is documented as using LRU.). For the 24-way L3 cache in the Itanium 2 6M (Madison), a bit per block was provided for NRU with an access to a block setting the bit corresponding to its set and way ("Itanium 2 Processor 6M: Higher Frequency and Larger L3 Cache", Stefan Rusu et al., 2004). This is similar to the clock page replacement algorithm.

I seem to recall reading elsewhere that the bits were cleared when all were set (rather than keeping the one that set the last unset bit) and that the victim was chosen by a find first unset scan of the bits. This would have the hardware advantage of only having to read the information (which was stored in distinct arrays from but nearby the L3 tags) on a cache miss; a cache hit could simply set the appropriate bit.  Incidentally, this type of NRU avoids some of the bad traits of true LRU (e.g., LRU degrades to FIFO in some cases and in some of these cases even random replacement can increase the hit rate).

Answer (score 7):

For Intel CPUs, the replacement policies are usually undocumented. I have done some experiments to uncover the policies in recent Intel CPUs, the results of which can be found on https://uops.info/cache.html. The code that I used is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/andreas-abel/nanoBench/tree/master/tools/CacheAnalyzer).

The following is a summary of my findings.

- **Tree-PLRU:** This policy is used by the L1 data caches of all CPUs that I tested, as well as by the L2 caches of the Nehalem, Westmere, Sandy Bridge, Ivy Bridge, Haswell and Broadwell CPUs.
- **Randomized Tree-PLRU:** Some Core 2 Duo CPUs use variants of Tree-PLRU in their L2 caches where either the lowest or the highest bits in the tree are replaced by (pseudo-)randomness.
- **MRU:** This policy is sometimes also called NRU. It uses one bit per cache block. An access to a block sets the bit to 0. If the last 1-bit was set to 0, all other bits are set to 1. Upon a miss, the first block with its bit set to 1 is replaced. This policy is used for the L3 caches of the Nehalem, Westmere, and Sandy Bridge CPUs.
- **Quad-Age LRU (QLRU):** This is a generalization of the MRU policy that uses two bits per cache block. Different variants of this policy are used for the L3 caches, starting with Ivy Bridge, and for the L2 caches, starting with Skylake.
- **Adaptive policies:** The Ivy Bridge, Haswell, and Broadwell CPUs can dynamically choose between two different QLRU variants. This is implemented via *set dueling*: A small number of dedicated sets always use the same QLRU variant; the remaining sets are "follower sets" that use the variant that performs better on the dedicated sets. See also http://blog.stuffedcow.net/2013/01/ivb-cache-replacement/.